# Is it OK to close over ActorLogging#log?

Tags: scala, akka

The code I'm working on fairly often has logging inside futures, using `log` from the `ActorLogging` trait. If I understand correctly, this isn't OK because this method uses `context` here: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Actor.scala#L316

Is it OK? If not, is it enough to save `log` to a `val` outside the future and use that?

Comment: You should provide code example so people can answer more accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val myLogging = log` is ok as `def log = akka.event.Logging(context.system, this)` (simplified version) returns thread-safe `LoggingAdapter` because it's using asynchronous event bus provided from `context.system` (`system.eventStream`). The only non-thread-safe version of `LoggingAdapter` is this:

```
 def apply(logSource: Actor): DiagnosticLoggingAdapter
```

as it's stated [in API docs](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/akka/event/Logging$.html#apply(logSource:akka.actor.Actor):akka.event.DiagnosticLoggingAdapter)

Basically, you can create any logger you want as `akka.event.Logging.apply`  is public.

P.S. Be aware that `log` will use your Actor's class for source name even if you pass it somewhere else.

P.S.2 You can also notice that `def log =` is already closed on your `eventBus` and actor (actor instance [is used only for naming](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/akka/event/LogSource.html)), so it might be even safe to call `log.blabla` directly from another thread. The only thing here it might cause reinitialization of `_log` as there is no double-checked locking. However, I'm not sure about some highly-optimized versions of JVM here - they might not follow "JavaMemoryModel" precisely especially when there is no @volatile annotation on `_log`.